# Android: Jetpack Compose How To Set expandable list expand only one list item

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack Compose expand only list item when user click on card if click on other card expand card hide and open other

Comment: You can create a data class with expanded property. Put that items inside a SnapshotStateList. When user clicks set every item expanded property to false and set expanded property of item that is clicked to true

Answer (score 0):

We can do like below

data class Item(
val id: Int,
val title: String,
val description: String
)

match Data class id when user click on list item

**In ViewModel class**

private val _expandedItemId = mutableStateOf<Int?>(null)

```
val expandedItemId get() = _expandedItemId.value

fun expandItem(itemId: Int) {
    _expandedItemId.value = itemId
}

fun collapseItem() {
    _expandedItemId.value = null
}
```

**When user click List Item**

```
        isExpanded = viewModel.expandedItemId == items.id,
            onItemClicked = {
                if (viewModel.expandedItemId == items.id) {
                    viewModel.collapseItem()
                } else {
                    viewModel.expandItem(items.id)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).